# What is payment period, and why is it equal 100 in this mortgage table?

Tags: mortgage, financial-literacy

Here’s the table:

[image]

I think the payment period is a month, but I don’t understand why it’s 100.

The image is taken from this Excel exercise: http://web.utk.edu/~dhouston/excel/exer3.pdf

Comment: did you follow the steps in the exercise?

Answer (score 2):

It is the 100th month of the mortgage term.

Using the `PMT()` function in Excel I generated this amortization schedule with the variables in your question:

[image: Amortization Table]

For some reason rather than showing the whole amortization table they chose to let you calculate for any given month what the split between principal and interest would be.

Edit: Added the formula text in the next cell over on the top portion to show interest percentage used and `PMT()` function format.

Comment: Your table is definitive.

Comment: Incidentally, when the Payment Period is 100 the Principal Paid is `=(1+B5)^(100-1)*(B6-B5*B3)` and the Interest Paid is `=B6-(1+B5)^(100-1)*(B6-B5*B3)`